# Unit testing umbraco based sites

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, inversion-of-control, umbraco

Is there a way to test code which relies on umbraco. i.e. within my model i'm calling getNode or using uquery to get nodes but i can't test those classes because they rely on umbraco...

i guess one way to resolve this issue is by mocking, but how can you mock uquery or nodefactory?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not convinced that CMS systems are naturally suited to unit testing as the output is not always as cut and dried as business logic should be.

But (there's always a but) you can mock the generation of nodes - manipulate them and check for errors at the least.  One example unit test would be to create a document type with some mandatory and some optional fields - then populate a content node with the mandatory fields only before then making an optional field mandatory - which should then error.  I don't think you can add properties as mandatory via code, though.

(Also see:
[How to add a property to a document type in Umbraco from code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10724473/how-to-add-a-property-to-a-document-type-in-umbraco-from-code) 
http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/api-cheatsheet/creating-a-document
http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/how-tos/working-with-document-types
)

Something like:

```
var alias = "aliasOfOptionalField";
var value = string.Empty;
var docType = "Textpage";

DocumentType dt = DocumentType.GetByAlias(docType); 
User author = User.GetUser(0); 
Document doc = Document.MakeNew("My new document", dt, author, 1018); 
doc.Publish(author);
umbraco.library.UpdateDocumentCache(doc.Id);

var newProperty = dt.AddPropertyType(new DataTypeDefinition(-49), alias, "test prop");

if (doc.HasProperty(alias))
{
   doc.getProperty(alias).Value = value;
   doc.Publish(new User(0));
   library.UpdateDocumentCache(doc.Id);
}
```